# Unable to import d3-tip into Typescript class

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I am trying to import **d3-tip** into one of my typescript classes.

`index.d.ts` of **d3-tip** looks like the following

```
import { Primitive } from "d3";

declare module "d3" {
    type TooltipDirection = ("n" | "s" | "e" | "w" | "nw" | "ne" | "sw" | "se");
    interface Tooltip {
        hide(): Tooltip;
        show(): Tooltip;
        show<Datum>(data: Datum[]): Tooltip;
        show(target: SVGElement): Tooltip;
        show<Datum>(data: Datum[], target: SVGElement): Tooltip;
        attr(name: string): string;
        attr(name: string, value: Primitive): Tooltip;
        attr<Datum>(name: string, value: (datum: Datum, index: number, outerIndex: number) => Primitive): Tooltip;
        attr<Datum>(obj: { [key: string]: Primitive | ((datum: Datum, index: number, outerIndex: number) => Primitive) }): Tooltip;
        style(name: string): string;
        style(name: string, value: Primitive, priority?: string): Tooltip;
        style<Datum>(name: string, value: (datum: Datum, index: number, outerIndex: number) => Primitive, priority?: string): Tooltip;
        style<Datum>(obj: { [key: string]: Primitive | ((datum: Datum, index: number, outerIndex: number) => Primitive) }, priority?: string): Tooltip;
        offset(): [number, number];
        offset(tuple: [number, number]): Tooltip;
        offset<Datum>(func: (datum: Datum, index: number, outerIndex: number) => [number, number]): Tooltip;
        direction(): TooltipDirection;
        direction(direction: TooltipDirection): Tooltip;
        direction<Datum>(func: (datum: Datum, index: number, outerIndex: number) => TooltipDirection): Tooltip;
        html(): string;
        html(content: string): Tooltip;
        html<Datum>(func: (datum: Datum, index: number, outerIndex: number) => string): Tooltip;
        rootElement(): HTMLElement;
        rootElement(element: HTMLElement): Tooltip;
        rootElement<Datum>(func: (datum: Datum, index: number, outerIndex: number) => HTMLElement): Tooltip;
        destroy(): Tooltip;
    }
    export function tip(): Tooltip;
}
```

I have tried to import like this

```
import * as d3tip from 'd3-tip';
```

or like this

```
import tip from 'd3-tip';
```

but in neither case I am able to use the `tip` function.

Comment: did you got a solution?

Comment: I have found a way, but far from being elegant. I import **d3-tip** using the following expression `import * as d3tip from 'd3-tip` and then use what I have imported like this `private tip = d3tip.default().attr('class', 'd3-tip').html((text: string) => {
    return text;
  });`. I still hope I can find a leaner way to do it.

Comment: I tried this , but it didnt worked. I am using  `@types/d3": "^5.5.0", "d3": "^5.7.0"` with angular 5

Comment: I forgot to say that I had to remove `@types/d3-tip` while I am still using `@types/d3": "^5.5.0"` - this now works for me, I am using Angular 7

Comment: @Pcci thanks it worked there was one more issur `getScreenCTM ` not defined , for which I followed this 

https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip/issues/231

Comment: @Picci, you should answer your own question which seems the best solution on the Internet pal

Answer (score 0):

You can try do it by this way:

```
import d3Tip from "d3-tip";
d3.tip = d3Tip;
```

Comment: This gives me an error: module ...@types/d3-tip/index has no default export

Answer (score 0):

Import, which works for me:
I am using d3v5 and angular 8

import d3Tip from "d3-tip";
const tip = d3Tip();